# Parameterization in SQL Server

Tags: database-design, azure-sql-database

I am struggling on understanding the need of Parameterization in SQL Server. I read, there are two types of parameterization but didn't understand its working and what are it effects on SQL Server or Database?

Comment: What are those two types? Please post a reference to what you read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide more details on what you're struggling to understand or what you're trying to accomplish you'll gather better answers, but right now your question is very lacking in details and unfortunately has a high chance of being closed.

To simply answer your question, if you're asking about the use cases for parameters in SQL Server, it is no different than the use cases for them in a functional or object oriented language, like C# and Java. Microsoft SQL Server (and typically other RDBMS) have types of entities known as Functions and Stored Procedures which accept parameters just like Functions and Methods in a functional programming language.

If your question is in regards to **Forced Parameterization** then that's a feature of Microsoft SQL Server. This feature allows the server to compare similar queries and generate parameters for the predicate values so that two similar queries that only differ in predicate values can cache and re-used the same query plan (since SQL Server caches query plans based on the exact string of the query text).

You can read more on how that feature works in Brent Ozar's [Forced Parameterization Enabled](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/forced-parameterization/).